# In an acute angled triangle, prove that $\sin A + \sin B + \sin C > 2$, where $0<A<B<\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

Is there any way to prove this? When I check intuitively by taking $A=0$ and $B=C=\frac{\pi}{2}$, the value of the expression becomes $2$ and as I changed the angles the value kept increasing in $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. I tried using Jensen's inequality but we get $\sin A + \sin B + \sin C <\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}$, which is of no use.

Comment: Try using $$\sin A + \sin B + \sin C = 4\cos\left(\frac A 2 \right)\cos\left(\frac B 2 \right)\cos\left(\frac C 2 \right)$$ and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried using that but it goes into a loop. I was not able to go forward.

Comment: Check what happens if $A$ and $B$ are close to $0$ and $C$ is close to $\pi$.

Comment: Try Karamata Inequality

Comment: Both duplicate targets found with Approach0: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csin(a)%2B%5Csin(b)%2B%5Csin(c)%5Cge%202%24

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin A + \sin B + \sin C=\sin A +\sin B + \sin(\pi-A-B)$$
$$=2\sin(\frac{A+B}{2})\cos(\frac{A-B}{2})+\sin(A+B)$$
$$=2\sin(\frac{A+B}{2})\cos(\frac{A-B}{2})+2\sin(\frac{A+B}{2})\cos(\frac{A+B}{2})$$
$$=2\sin(\frac{A+B}{2})\Bigl(\cos(\frac{A-B}{2})+\cos(\frac{A+B}{2})\Bigr)$$
$$=4\sin(\frac{A+B}{2})\Bigl(\cos\frac{A}{2}\cos\frac{B}{2}\Bigr)$$
$$=4\sin(\frac{\pi-C}{2})\Bigl(\cos\frac{A}{2}\cos\frac{B}{2}\Bigr)$$
$$=4\cos\frac{C}{2}\cos\frac{A}{2}\cos\frac{B}{2}$$
$$=4\cos\frac{A}{2}\cos\frac{B}{2}\cos\frac{C}{2}$$
$$0<A<B<\frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$0<\frac{A}{2}<\frac{B}{2}<\frac{\pi}{4}$$
$$4\cos\frac{A}{2}\cos\frac{B}{2}\cos\frac{C}{2} >4\cos\frac{C}{2}$$

when $A=0, B=0$.
During this situation, $C=\frac{\pi}{2}$

So,
$$\sin A + \sin B + \sin C=4\cos\frac{A}{2}\cos\frac{B}{2}\cos\frac{C}{2} >4\cos\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}}{2}=2\sqrt{2}>2$$

Comment: Use ```\left(``` and ```\right)``` for adjusting the size of brackets. For example, $$(\frac69)\text{ vs }\left(\frac69\right)$$

Comment: Thank you, shall keep that in mind!!

Comment: One more thing: when nesting brackets, you can use ```\big```, ```\Big``` and ```\Bigg``` also. For example, $$\Bigg(\Big(\big((x)\big)\Big)\Bigg)$$

Answer (score 0):

I try to use comment but failed. so I just comments here. For a acute triangle, we must have all angles less than $\frac{\pi}{2}$, so $4\cos\frac{A}{2}\cos\frac{B}{2}\cos\frac{C}{2} $ can be direct to get the result.